# How to recover unmountable sparsebundles from a Time Machine that "needs internal disk repair"

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, time-capsule, sparsebundle

After trying to recover old family photos and videos from my Time-Machine by repairing and duplicating unmountable sparsebundle-files, it appears that I completely messed up the entire Time-Machine.

Background:
We used to utilize Time Machine to backup three different iMacs and additionally used it as a Wi-Fi. I remember that quite a few years back it started to blink orange and we stopped using it. As one of the iMac's broke down several years ago and I lost access to most of the data (luckily saved some of the photos before) the only way to gain access to these again are through the backups on the semi-broken Time-Machine.
Last week I decided to start the Time Machine again and give it a go.

Here's what I've done this since plugging in the Time Machine again:

1. I went through a hard-reset to reset the password and gained access to the sparsebundle files again
2. First, the sparsebundles mounted as "Time-Machine-Backups" but it was empty, despite being 500GB large. Later on, the sparsebundle didn't even mount and I was notified "no mountable file-systems"
3. I tried repairing one of the sparsebundles using Apple's Disk Utility - things took too long so I started to look for alternatives and then came across a tutorial to repair it via the Terminal.
4. I ran:

- sudo su -
- chflags -R nouchg XXX.sparsebundle
- hdiutil attach -nomount - readwrite -noverify -noautofsck XXX.sparsebundle
- tail -f /var/log/fsck_hfs.log
- fsck_hfs -drfy /dev/diskXsX
- hdiutil detach /dev/diskXsX

The first time I ran these everything went successfully but the sparsebundles were still not mountable. Strangely a few days later it worked when I ran fsck_hfs -p /dev/diskXsX before detaching. Although I had intended to first try to repair a less important sparsebundle (not to mess up the most important sparsebundle), the most important sparsebundle was up and running again and for the first time in years and I was given access to all lost family pictures & videos again!

5. As the Time-Machine configuration was somewhat off my Wi-Fi was not working properly, so I decided to shut off the Time-Machine and restart it once I would get a new external USB HDD to save all the data.
6. With a new external USB HDD ready to save all seemingly-recovered data, I plugged the Time Machine in again - unfortunately, the sparsebundles were unmountable again. I was in shock and thus re-did everything described in step 4, this time without success.
7. I decided to work with copies of the sparsebundles so I tried to copy & paste it onto the external USB HDD. From this point on things went downhill - the sparsebundle was somehow compressed and shrank from 500GB to 30KB. I then tried to use "duplicate" instead of "copy" which failed and later resulted in being notified something like "Data" (the folder on the Time Machine that contains all sparsebundles) "not found".
8. A day later, when I was trying to access the Time-Machine via Finder, I was notified something like "time capsule airport cannot be opened because the original item cannot be found", so I decided to check AirPort-Utility. In AirPort Utility it said the DNS along with other network-related configurations are off.
9. I then switched off "create wireless network" under "Wireless" in AirPort-Utility, which resulted in "internal disk needs repair". At this point, the Time Machine is no longer showing up in Finder.

Obviously the first step now should be to at least make the Time-Machine working again by fixing the "internal disk needs repair" issue and later on work on making the sparsebundles mountable again. What's the best way to achieve this?

For the case that fixing the internal disk issue does not work, I consider the following options:

1. Archive the Time-Machine HDD to an external, Mac-OS-formatted USB HDD using AirPort Utility and then try to make the the sparsebundles mountable again.
2. Dissamble the Time-Machine and try to recover the sparsebundles by reading the HDD via a USB-SATA cable. Then try to make them mountable again.
3. If step 2 does not work, let Disk Warrior read through the HDD.
4. Take it to a data recovery centre.

I would highly value any input - thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Our questions seem related.  My time machine sparsebundle is "dirty" but mounts.  I would like to know [How do I fix a sparsebundle that does not fsck but mounts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/431229/109212).  I play with a copy, keeping the original Time Machine bundle on the NAS.  The `fsck` gave me a Disk Full error, which I fixed with a `hdiutil resize -size 1.0t foo.sparsebundle`.  Once it mounted I also issued a `find Backups.backpdb -print > /dev/null` from inside the bundle file system, detached and `chflags  -R uchg,schg foo.sparsebundle`.  DiskWarrior did not help.